# Remove word-wrap offset in ACE editor

Tags: javascript, word-wrap, ace-editor

I need to remove offseting 4 " " which are automatically created after breaking line in ACE editor

I tried using `editor.setTabSize(0)` that worked as well, but then I can't ident code by using TAB, as it throws "undefined" instead into code. I searched on ACE webpage, but there is nothing as that, and when searched forums, it told something with `setBehaviosrEnabled`, but that didn't work either

Any idea how to get rid of those 4 spaces?

Issue:
[image]

Code:

```
var editor = ace.edit("edittext");
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: Infinity
});
editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
editor.setBehavioursEnabled(false);
editor.renderer.setOption('showLineNumbers', false);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is controlled by [indentedSoftWrap](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/b6991adb41cf89eceb916eb8b6db0a793c6abecb/lib/ace/editor.js#L2690) setting in ace, you cn turn it off by running

```
editor.setOption("indentedSoftWrap", false);
```

behaviours setting is completely unrelated and controls automatic insertion of closing brackets and tags.

So your code from the above would become

```
var editor = ace.edit("edittext");
editor.setOptions({
    maxLines: Infinity,  // this is going to be very slow on large documents
    useWrapMode: true,   // wrap text to view
    indentedSoftWrap: false, 
    behavioursEnabled: false, // disable autopairing of brackets and tags
    showLineNumbers: false, // hide the gutter
    theme: "ace/theme/xcode"
});
```

Comment: Google didnt point me to this answer... StackOverFlow did! Thanks man!

Comment: Just a side note: "useWrapMode" seems it should be "wrap" --> https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2358